# Adding a global namespace to .net Webbrowser Control

Tags: c#, vb.net, webbrowser-control

Scenario:
A widget developer codes using HTML and javascript.
My vb.net application allows developers to create widgets for other users.

in javascript you can call window.external to comunicate with the host windows scripting object and I would like to add a helper namespace with many functions to aid the development of widgets similar to windows sidebar's System namespace.

Problem:
So I could allow developers to use Window.External.System but how can I just allow them to access System directly without using Window.External?

Microsoft adds a System Namespace to windows sidebar gadgets host window which is just an internet explorer server window.

Please help!
I know this is a fairly complicated question.

Comment: I would like to try and make it compatible with sidebar gadgets so using window.external is not really an option.

Okay - so more googling revealed inteface IHTMLWindow2
MSDN reference here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741505(VS.85).aspx

If i could implement this interface in my vb.net application I could add my own properties and functions and also override some of the standard ones.

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add to the page that your WebBrowser control displays a series of JavaScript functions that forward to Window.External.

Widget makers can then code with the simple syntax and your .NET helpers are called through Window.External.